# Insert element in React Native ListView

Tags: listview, react-native

I am struggling to dynamically insert a `View` into `ListView` component in React Native. Eventually, I want to get something like google images here:
[image]

I have list of boxes that are listed with `ListView` and following styles

```
renderListStyle: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    }
```

So the boxes are displayed correctly but now I need to dynamically insert a View between rows. For example when I click on box number four, the view component appears under the first row. When user clicks on 8 then view component appears after the second row etc. [image]

Any ideas how to accomplish it? I checked the renderSeparator prop of the `ListView` but cannot quite get what I need. Maybe someone had such an issue before?

appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Is your listview rendering each individual box as a row? What if you have all 3 boxes set as a row with the view you want included and if any of those 3 boxes are clicked it will show the view. Here's a rough sketch of something it might look like:

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={(rowData) => (
    <View>
      <Box onPress={this.showView} /> //the 3 boxes will prob be wrapped in 
      <Box onPress={this.showView} /> //another view to set those to 'row' flexDirection
      <Box onPress={this.showView} />
      <YourView show={this.state.show} />
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was also thinking about it, but maybe there is another way to do it. I actually wanted to put 3 Boxes per row(now there is one) and include the View as separator. But let's see. Thank you for the answer!